# Adding Janrain library to eclipse project?

Tags: android, eclipse, janrain

I am trying to import janrain to my eclipse ide. I'm trying to follow the directions, but I don't see the folder that this section refers to called JREngage

```
Import the JREngage project into your workspace:
Choose File > Import.
Choose General > Existing Projects into Workspace.
Click Select root directory.
Click Browse.
Browse to engage.android, and click Open.
Click Deselect All.
Check JREngagePhonegapPlugin.
**Check JREngage.**
Click Finish.
http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/mobile-libraries/phonegapcordova/
```

When I browse to the github directory: github.com/janrain/engage.android.git
I don't see the folder JREngage anywhere. Am I doing something wrong or has the directory just not been updated correctly?

EDIT:
I am having trouble following the method that youæve given. For some reason the     createSocialPublishingFragment is unable to import. Hereæs the errorØ

```
  06-12 16:01:43.966: E/dalvikvm(7472): Could not find class 'com.janrain.android.engage.ui.JRPublishFragment', referenced from method     com.janrain.android.engage.JREngage.createSocialPublishingFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Stagleton. We just updated JUMP for Android to v4.0.7, and the updated steps for importing to Eclipse have also been updated. Go to https://github.com/janrain/jump.android/blob/master/Eclipse_Import_Guide.md